# Main language not reselected correctly if previous section ends with other language and section title starts with other language

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia, debugging, bugs

I have an issue with XeLaTeX with a document with two languages, Hebrew and English. I use a different font for Hebrew (here DejaVu Sans, but any font will do).

The problem is that when (1) a section ends with Hebrew text and (2) the next section title starts with Hebrew text, the remainder of the document, as well as the table of contents, appears in the font used for Hebrew. For some reason the system does not switch back to the main font (see example below).

I only have this issue on one machine (out of two). The problematic machine is running Debian Bookworm with TeX Live 2022 installed from [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html). `xelatex --version` gives:

```
XeTeX 3.141592653-2.6-0.999994 (TeX Live 2022)
kpathsea version 6.3.4
Copyright 2022 SIL International, Jonathan Kew and Khaled Hosny.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the XeTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the XeTeX source.
Primary author of XeTeX: Jonathan Kew.
Compiled with ICU version 70.1; using 70.1
Compiled with zlib version 1.2.11; using 1.2.11
Compiled with FreeType2 version 2.11.1; using 2.11.1
Compiled with Graphite2 version 1.3.14; using 1.3.14
Compiled with HarfBuzz version 3.4.0; using 3.4.0
Compiled with libpng version 1.6.37; using 1.6.37
Compiled with pplib version v2.05 less toxic i hope
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.13.0; using 2.14.1
```

On my other machine there is no problem. This machine runs Debian Bullseye with TeX Live 2022 installed from the same source. The only difference in `xelatex --version` is:

```
Compiled with fontconfig version 2.13.0; using 2.13.1
```

So the problematic system uses a newer fontconfig (I don't know how I can use the older version on the newer system to test if that solves the issue). All packages (both `apt` and `tlmgr`) are up to date on both systems.

Any thoughts what might fix the issue?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{DejaVu Sans}
\newcommand{\heb}[1]{\bgroup\normalfont\hebrewfont\RL{#1}\egroup}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First section}
\begin{hebrew}
    This section ends with Hebrew text.
\end{hebrew}
\section{\heb{אב} Section title starts with Hebrew}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here everything except "text. Hebrew with ends section This" and "אב" should be in the default font, rather than DejaVu Sans.

Comment: Use \selectlanguage to switch between languages, that is safer.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks, that (concretely: replacing `\hebrewfont` with `\selectlanguage{hebrew}` in the definition of `\heb`) works! Do you want to write an answer? It can be a stub and I can add a screenshot, if you want, but the credit should go to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [suggested by Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/678025/main-language-not-reselected-correctly-if-previous-section-ends-with-other-langu#comment1683160_678025), using

```
\newcommand{\heb}[1]{\bgroup\selectlanguage{hebrew}\RL{#1}\egroup}
```

fixes the issue.

[image]